# TCPDF list item margin

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Couldn't find it anywhere. Having list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

and CSS:

```
ul li, ol li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

While previewing list in browser, `margin-bottom` is interpreted correctly. Unfortunately, `TCPDF` somehow doesn't recognize this style (while recognizing other parts of included css file). Is there any trick/hack to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried padding? PDF's are annoying to work with.

Comment: Tried working with millimetres, rather than pixels? `margin-bottom: 25mm;`

Comment: Have you tried line-height   ?

Comment: Line height maybe could work, but not in case of having multiple lines per each list entry. Using milimeters for padding/margin won't work either.

Comment: Line height is worked ?

Comment: Yes, it worked but it won't solve my problem as I have only multiline points in my list.

Answer (score 10):

tcpdf allows to define the vertical spaces for HTML tags, see Method [setHtmlVSpace](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71cec8b4c54a78429640e4767648e73e) of [TCPDF Class Documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html), use:

```
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace(array(
    'li' => array(
        'h' => 5, // margin in mm
    ) 
));
```

The name of the html-Element is the key (li) and h specifies the vertical space

Comment: Please specify a bit more about the code you posted. Usually answers come with a bit of explanation.

Comment: your suggested links are broken. http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71cec8b4c54a78429640e4767648e73e  http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and unfortunately it didn't help solve my problem. If you experience this issue (weird line spacing under the list items), you have a number of choices:

1. Use `ul {line-height:0}` to remove margins around the outer UL. *OR* `$pdf->setHtmlVSpace(array('ul'=>array(0=>array('h'=>0,'n'=>0),1=>array('h'=>0,'n'=>0))));`
2. The **key** bit which worked for me re the LI items was actually using a `<p>` inside the LI. For some reason without it the spacing went crazy. With it - it fixed it. `<li><p>Your content</p></li>`

Comment: `setHtmlVSpace` function worked for me to reduce un-neccessary margin-padding-height attributes. Thanks Antony.