# How to use setHtmlVSpace in TCPDF to reduce vertical space between list elements?

Tags: php, tcpdf

My pdf document currently looks like this.
[image]

I want to reduce the space between the li elements. I was trying to use inline style for the li tags, and after many unsuccesful attempts I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876755/6041838)

```
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace(array(
    'li' => array(
        'h' => 0, // margin in mm
    ) 
));

$html ='
<span style="text-align:justify;">
<ul>
    <li><p>1.- Los datos de los bienes, arrendamientos o servicios a cotizar (mismos que se especifican en el anexo de la solicitud de cotización).</p></li>
    <li><p>2.- Condiciones de entrega:</p></li>
    <li><p>En una sola exhibición de <u>cantidad de días señalada en documento anexo</u>&nbsp;días naturales posteriores a la recepción de la orden de surtimiento.</p><ul><li>Entregas parciales con una vigencia máxima (fechas o plazo) <b><u>N/A.</u></b></li><li>El lugar de entrega será: <b><u>El señalado en el documento anexo.</u></b></li></ul></li>
<ul></span>';
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);
```

This is my code right now, but still the spacing is not changing.

Comment: What? It looks like the `<p>` tags causing this with them `margin-bottom` style

Comment: @AlonEitan I removed thep tags and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: the CSS property for margin and padding is not supported in TCPDF. Instead I added line-height in my span tag to obtain desired spacing.

```
$htmlData = '
<span style="text-align:justify; line-height: 21px;">
<ul>
    <li>1.- Los datos de los bienes, arrendamientos o servicios a cotizar (mismos que se especifican en el anexo de la solicitud de cotización).</li>
    <li>2.- Condiciones de entrega:</li>
    <li>En una sola exhibición de <u>cantidad de días señalada en documento anexo</u>&nbsp;días naturales posteriores a la recepción de la orden de surtimiento.<ul><li>Entregas parciales con una vigencia máxima (fechas o plazo) <b><u>N/A.</u></b></li><li>El lugar de entrega será: <b><u>El señalado en el documento anexo.</u></b></li></ul></li>
    <li>3.- Considerar en su cotización que el pago es a los 20 días naturales posteriores a la entrega de la factura, previa entrega de los bienes o prestación de los servicios a satisfacción.</li>
<ul></span>';


$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlData, true, 0, true, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Even it's an old question, here is the way I deal with that under TCPDF:

```
ul {
    line-height: 0px;
   }   
li {
       line-height: 12px;
   }
```

Notice you must have both ul and li as if you just have ul, it changes also the space between line in the li. With ul line height at 0 the first line of the li is just after the line before the ul tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use tcpdf.php v. 6.4.1, last updated 2021-03-27. In your sample you have tag P into tag LI, so please reduce both their default heights by setting h to a small number >0 e.g. 0.01 (*FYI: near the end you have added UL instead of </UL*):

```
$tagvs = [
  'p' => [
    ['h'=>0.1, ],
    ['h'=>0.1, ]
  ],
  'li' => [
    ['h'=>0.1, ],
  ],
];
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove unnecessary vertical height/spaces from `p` tag in `TCPDF` then you can use below code. I worked for me.

> $tagvs = array('p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0), 1 =>
> array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0)));
>
> $pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);

Thanks for asking this question.